# What is the best way to handle a JSON-RPC response using MooTools

Tags: javascript, json, mootools, rpc

I want to generate code for a web service using JSON-RPC. The generated code will provide generated methods for the client to use. In traditional JavaScript I guess one would use callbacks assigned to each method, but I am unsure on how to do this in a proper MooTools fashion.

```
var Service = new Class({
Implements: [Options, Events],
options: {
    url: 'http://localhost/lol/JSON',
    ...
    send: function(opts) {
        var JSONrpc = new Request.JSON({
         ...
        });

    JSONrpc.send(JSON.encode({'method': opts.methodname || this.options.methodname, 
                              'params': opts.params || this.options.params}));
},
    ...
    //The methods to be generated
    loginUser: function(username, password) {       
        this.send({'methodname': 'loginUser', 'params': [username, password]});
    },
    logoffUser: function(username) {
            this.send({'methodname': 'logoffUser'});
    },
    getProfile: function(username) {
       this.send({'methodname': 'getProfile', 'params': [username]});
    },
```

What is the best way to handle the response properly? Should I have an event for each method? Should I use the id to identify the call?
What is the MooTools way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would Extend Request.JSON, overriding the send and complete/success methods where I will dispatch events which parse `this.data.methodname` so you have it available in the parent class Service, where you can bubble it to the Service instances, if you have to.

Comment: I came up with a solution where I have all the calls stored in an array with a unique ID. When the call returns, it iterates the array and tries to find the corresponding call. If it finds it, it deletes the ID from the array. This solution requires me to generate an event for each generated method, but I think that isn't a bad solution. Does that sound decent, or should I do it another way?